# Range.Address and Range.End issue

Tags: excel, vba

The code below:

```
Debug.Print ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
Debug.Print ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.End(xlUp).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
Debug.Print ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.End(xlDown).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

is returning the following data:

```
R22C14:R513C14
R1C14
R513C14
```

Why? Shouldn't second output line be R22C14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on whether or not there is anything in the cells in the initial range selected. If there is data in the selected cells, hitting Ctrl-Up will take you to the first cell in the selected region. If there is no data in the region hitting Ctrl-Up will take you to either row 1 of the first column selected (what you're seeing), or to the next cell it finds with data (if you had selected a range *below* some cells with data).

Comment: I open a blank sheet, I fill adjacent cells pertaining to the same column with data, I select any of those "used" cells, and then I aways get the same: CurrentRegion.End(xlUp) always gives me Row 1 as output, which is not true, because Row 1 is empty, clean, "virgin".

Comment: @strajano Can you give me a specific example of what and where you're entering data and what range you're selecting?

Comment: Ok, lets go: I am using Excel 2016 with Windows 7. I open a new workbook. I fill the following cells with data, manually: cell(3,3) = "a"; cell(4,3) = "b"; cell(5,3) = "c". I select any of those fullfilled cells. Then, when I execute "Debug.Print ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.End(xlUp).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)", I always get the same answer: R1C3, no matter if the selected cell is (3,3), (4,3) or (5,3). How could I get the right answer: R3C3?

Comment: @strajano I think `Selection.End(xlUp)` behaves a little bit more how you want it to. However, if I only have the first cell selected (C3) it still returns R1C3. Same result if I have the whole range selected (C3:C5). It only takes me to the beginning of the region (R3C3) if I have some lower subset selected.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with an alternative. But for me it is weird that the opposite direction, CurrentRegion.End(xlDown), works exactly as expected.